# Difference between cl and g++ compilers?

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++, g++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <chrono>

template<class Resolution = std::chrono::milliseconds>
class ExecutionTimer {
public:
    using Clock = std::conditional_t<std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::is_steady,
        std::chrono::high_resolution_clock,
        std::chrono::steady_clock>;
    ExecutionTimer() = default;

    ~ExecutionTimer() {
        std::cout
            << "Elapsed: "
            << std::chrono::duration_cast<Resolution>(Clock::now() - mStart).count()
            << std::endl;
    }
private:
    Clock::time_point mStart = Clock::now();
};

int main() {
    ExecutionTimer<> timer;

    std::vector<int> v(50000000);
    std::sort(std::begin(v), std::end(v));
    return 0;
}
```

I tried to compile the above C++ code with 2 different compilers and observed the difference in the Running time of both .exe files as

I ran using environment variable 

  *"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.10.25017\bin\Hostx64\x64"*

```
CL  ->  cl /ehsc Benchmark.cpp
        364 (ms)
g++ ->  g++ -std=c++17 Benchmark.cpp -o bench17
        16565 (ms)
```

Can someone tell me why there a huge difference?

Comment: Benchmarking without enabling optimizations is a waste of time. Rerun your experiments after adding `-O3` to the g++ command line and `/O2` to the VC++ command line.

Comment: Thanks it worked, but still i get 974 (ms) when i run as
g++ -O3 -std=c++17 BenchmarkTest.cpp -o benchO3.

Comment: try putting your code [in this site](https://godbolt.org/) and see the difference in the output of your different compilers

Comment: Because they're different compilers and optimize differently, they're bound to produce different assembly. If there's a huge difference with optimizations enabled, then open an issue for the relevant compiler.

Comment: What g++ did you use? If it's the one distributed with linux for windows (or even worse cygwin) there are simply going to be execution-time hitches for even trivial programs. Now if you get significantly different results even after optimization and running both on native platforms ...

Comment: Creating a huge vector is not take so long time as sorting of them. This time difference may be only if one of the compilers "see" that the vector is filled by default values that are equal and the sort function is not called in assembly. My versions of compilers not optimize the code in this way, thus I can't see the result assembly and check this assumption.

Comment: Try to initialize `v` with large random numbers. Supposedly the two implementations handle a lot of zero numbers differently.

Answer (score 0):

By default, g++ does not perform any optimization at all.  This is especially problematic for code using the standard templates, which are almost completely implemented outside the pre-compiled standard library, so the lack of optimization is very visible.

I don't have the Microsoft compiler to test, but on my system, enabling `-O2` brings down the execution time from more than 25 seconds to less than one second.